# What is the name of the functor $Sp_k$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, notation, representation-theory

I'm seeing this in Jantzen's "*Representations of algebraic groups*".
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the functor representing $\text{Spec}(k)$. In other words, it's the functor $A \mapsto \text{Hom}_k(k, A)$, and the set $\text{Hom}_k(k,A)$ ($k$-algebra maps from $k$ to $A$) has one element for any $k$-algebra $A$: this is almost by definition.

Comment: Yes that I understand. I was just wondering about the name of the functor, for ease of searching.

Comment: Ah right. Yeah it's typically denoted Spec in most other sources, I'm guessing the weird $\text{Sp}_k$ notation is to emphasize that it's a functor, not a locally ringed space. It's called the "spectrum" of a ring: Jantzen's notation in Section 1.3 is pretty standard.